# How to Only Allow Users Access to Specific Files?

Tags: permissions, freebsd, webserver

I have a user that is used to run my server. Ideally, it would only have write access to the server's log files, and only have read access to the document-root. How would I do this on FreeBSD 11?

Comment: A combo of `chown` and `chmod` on the log file and the document root. What have you tried?

Comment: Use ACL's see https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=setfacl&sektion=1

Comment: @val0x00ff I get the error: Argument list too long. I'm using setfacl -m u:server:--- 'find .' The goal is to give the user access to no files, then specifically enumerate the files to which it should have access.

Comment: @Tigger I have tried to use Access Control Lists, but I get the error that acl_get_file() operation isn't supported. To fix this, I have tried going to Single User Mode, and running tunefs -a enable /dev/gpt/rootfs but to no avail.